# How to set instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier to the global variable?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two different entry points:

```
let entryPoint: UITabBarController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
```

and

```
let entryPoint: WelcomeController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WelcomeController") as! WelcomeController
```

How can I set `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to this global `entryPoint` var? It's difficult for me, because they have two different ViewController types: `UITabBarController` and `ViewController`.

So, I want like

```
var entryPoint?
```

and later

```
entryPoint: UITabBarController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
```

or

```
entryPoint: WelcomeController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WelcomeController") as! WelcomeController
```

Comment: Try putting if else condition by creating a bool variable.

Comment: No, I need the global variable and I cannot create it without adding the type @the_UB

Answer (score 1):

Solutions will depend on how you intend to use entryPoint later on.

if you don't have any class specific uses or don't mind a bit of type casting, you could always declare entry point as a UIViewController:

```
var entryPoint:UIViewController?
```

swift will accept both assignments because all the classes are subclasses of UIViewController.

If you want to use specific properties later, you will need to check the actual class of the variable

for example:

```
if let tabBarEntry = entryPoint as? UITabBarController
{
   tabBarEntry.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

Comment: No! It's not exactly what I've asked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that I had adopted for an app.

I'll outline it briefly and then provide sample code.

What you need to do is:
Save a value in `UserDefaults` so that later you can fetch it to determine your entry point.

To set the value in `UserDefaults`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("TabBarController", forKey: "entryPoint")
```

To retrieve the value

```
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "entryPoint")
```

In your code you can check what should be your entry point as

```
    let entry = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "entryPoint") as! String
    var entryPoint?

    if (entry == "TabBarController")
    {
        entryPoint = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
    }
    else
    {
        entryPoint = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WelcomeController") as! WelcomeController
    }
```

> But once you have set `entryPoint` object , it's type will be set either as
>   a `UITabBarController` or `WelcomeController` **and will remain the same throughout the execution of the app**.